# Animation inside Circle onTouch

Tags: android, animation

I have a design where it consist of an emergency button which is attached below. My requirement is that when i touch this button a color should start to fill up as a stroke on the outer circle  and this touch should be a long press of about 2 seconds and within this time limit the filling up of the color should be completed.Also if i remove my touch then the process of filling up should stop.I have already tried several examples but everything so far is progress bar and it does not meet up with my requirement.If anyone knows the answer please let know.Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone knows the answer please let know

You need to create own View: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html and deal with touches yourself.